# Laravel 5.1 LaravelShoppingcart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

**however when outputting the value of my cart:**

```
{{ \Cart::subtotal() }}
```

> I get 1,000.00

**When trying to get the VAT value I divide the sum**

```
{{ \Cart::subtotal() / 100 * 20 }}
```

> I get 0.2

This should return 200?

I know I should use the \Cart::tax() function however this isn't right in the UK.

I've also tried wrapping the subtotal in the number_format() function however this returns an error **A non well formed numeric value encountered.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs:

> Cart::subtotal($decimals, $decimalSeperator, $thousandSeperator);

The thousand separator causes your problem,
so you could do this:

`\Cart::subtotal(2,'.','')`

Comment: You would want to keep the decimals to have the accurate calculation. It's the comma that is causing the problem ;)